# Add negative margin to span class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a -15px margin to a span class but the objects are not moving.

I have added this to the class:

```
.pricingbox-circle span.price-large {
    margin:-15px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 68px;
}
```

However nothing happens.

I am trying to move the pricing up inside the circle

I have created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/paL776d9/

Comment: add `display: block` or `display: inline-block`to span.

Comment: You need to add `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` to span, it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The `span` is by default an `inline` level element which doesn't support negative margin.

To go around this, change the `display` property to `inline-block`.

```
.pricingbox-circle span.price-large {
    display: inline-block; /* overwriting the default which is inline`
    margin:-15px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 68px;
}
```

Edited the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paL776d9/1/).